# Why does my page work in Firefox but not in Safari or Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, safari

http://pastorcarepbr.com/

I HTML validated it and it looks just the way I want it to in Firefox but in Chrome and Safari the #main div doesn't have the background color showing and the break tag with css set to clear both doesn't clear the way it does in Firefox.

I can't figure out what I did wrong considering it works fine in Firefox and it also HTML validates. Can anybody take a look at it?

---

<strike>Also, is this a coding error or a Web Host problem? I keep getting an old and new version of the Web page depending on if I do a simple refresh or a Ctrl+Shift+R refresh.</strike>

As mrtsherman and Nicole said, it was just the cache. Private browsing shows consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a `<div style='clear:both'></div>` right before the `#main` closing tag. I shouldn't have anything to do with your browsers cache or web hosting.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly! So, clearing a a break doesn't work then or is there some other reason this works?

Comment: When you float something it basically collapses into itself, putting the clear there resets the document flow and therefore fixes the problem

Comment: I know that but I had a a break tag there with the class "breaker" and the styles for breaker where clear: both. What I'm wondering is why it didn't work for the break tag, just for my own personal enlightenment.

Comment: ahh sorry I misunderstood. I'm not sure why but it never works with anything besides a div. I think another style and `clear:both` has to be on it for it to work properly. No idea why, its just another one of those mysteries ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably a caching issue. The page seems to render fine to me. Here is quick tip. To take caching out of the picture, open up an incognito/private browsing instance. Then let us know what you see. I think this will resolve it. If this is the problem then you can version your CSS files by appending `.css?version=1.1` for example. If you do this server side you can append a timestamp to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

:)

To help out a bit more 1. You should provide the code you are working with. It is a major help in trying to figure out what is going wrong. And 2. the old and new version of the web site sounds to me like you need to clear your browser cache.